# return redirect() invalidating the code before in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with Flask and I have a page with 2 sections: one where you select from a range of check-boxes and the submit your selection and one where all of your selections are placed in a text-area:

```
<section id="about">
  <div class="main-container">
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% for event in events: %}
      <input type="checkbox" name="new_events" value="{{ event.name }} @ {{ event.venue }} at {{ event.start_date }}">  {{ event.name }} @ {{ event.venue }} at {{ event.start_date }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" align="center">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="services">
  <div class="main-container">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <textarea>
        {% for new_event in new_events %}
          {{ new_event }}
        {% endfor %}
      </textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Then what I'm trying to do is once you clicked on the Submit button the page to redirect to the second section (id=services):

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    events = db.session.query(Event)
    new_events = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        new_events = request.form.getlist('new_events')
        return redirect(url_for('index', _anchor="services", new_events=new_events))

    return render_template('index.html', events=events, new_events=new_events)
```

If I run the above code by commenting out the "return redirect()", the text area gets populated without any problems. I just need to scroll down to it to see it. Once I activate the "return redirect()" code it will scroll down to my text area, but it does not get populated anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by eliminating:

```
return redirect(url_for('index', _anchor="services", new_events=new_events)
```

and calling a simple scroll function in my jinja2 template inside the second section:

```
 {% if new_events %}
    <script>
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top }, 500);
    </script>
  {% endif %}
```